# How to convert float into int in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

This is my code:

```
users.age.mean().astype(int64)
```

(where users is the name of dataframe and age is a column in it)

This is the error I am getting:

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-10b672e7f7ae> in <module>
----> 1 users.age.mean().astype(int64)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Comment: `int(users.age.mean())`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`users.age.mean()` returns a float not a series. Floats don't have `astype`, only pandas series.

Try:

`x = numpy.int64(users.age.mean())`

Or:

`x = int(users.age.mean())`

Answer (score 1):

Try `int` before your function example:

```
X = int(users.age.mean())
```

Hope it helps!